# White empty space in Android Layout fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

In my Android app I have a login screen which works fine so far. It is structured in a root `ScrollView`, which has a vertical `LinearLayout` names rootLayer. In that rootLayer, I have four consecutive `LinearLayout`'s as you can see in following xml layout file. But I only show three at the same time. Depending on if logged in or off, either  *1st* (loggedOffLayer) **or** *2nd* (loggedInLayer) layer; **AND** then the *3rd* and fourth *4th* (grey color) always:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loggedOffLayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:visibility="visible">
     <!-- one two views and buttons-->
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loggedInLayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/loggedOffLayer"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible">
            <!-- some labels, textviews and buttons -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/about_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayer"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:visibility="visible">
            <!-- labels with about text -->
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomLayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@color/light_background"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- imageviews and labels with pictures and legal text-->
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When I am logged in every thing is fine. But when I am logged off, as in following [image: screenshot], there is a white empty space (red arrow) after my last layer (grey).

**How can I stick the last layer to the bottom, so that there is no white stripe in every case?**

Comment: is it because you set height to 120dp of bottomlayer, try with wrap_content

Comment: Change height from 120dp to wrap_content or match_parent and check it.

Comment: Yeah, wrap_content solved my issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this code:---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:fillViewport="true"
>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.8">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loggedOffLayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:visibility="visible">
            <!-- one two views and buttons-->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loggedInLayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/loggedOffLayer"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible">
            <!-- some labels, textviews and buttons -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/about_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayer"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:visibility="visible">
            <!-- labels with about text -->
        </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomLayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- imageviews and labels with pictures and legal text-->
  </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

using this code your  bottomLayer stick at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is very hard to do because you are using `scroll layout` and `scroll layout` will grow and shrink as you add or remove `widgets` from it.

Also it will differ from display to display `resolutions`. For low `resolution` `scroll layout` will grow and for high resolution `scroll layout` will shrink as there is lot of space on the screen.